# Reading all files in folder in matlab

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loop through files in a folder in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621846/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-in-matlab)

I have a few folders with around 50 csv files in each and I have to read each file and place it in a variable named same as a file but without extension .csv. Files are 2x15000 matrix. Can anyone help? I've searched the Internet, but nothing works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Did you _really_ search the internet? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621846/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-in-matlab) appears first in [Google's search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=looping+through+files+in+a+folder+matlab&rlz=1C1CHEU_enIL452IL452&oq=looping+through+files+in+a+folder+matlab&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l2j62l3.7945&sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)...

Comment: @EitanT not exactly a duplicate, I would say.

Comment: @angainor it's pretty damn close, if you ask me.

Comment: @EitanT Don't think so. How about loading the files into variables named as those files? Nothing there about it.

Comment: I saw that, but I can't figure out how to put it into a variable named as a file. I'm not even sure if it's posible. I don't want it all to be a giant field, but a 50 different variables

Comment: Shouldn't one just consider a cell array for storing? If one needs to build up the variable name at run time (eval & co.) to access, she would loose performance (and patience)..

Answer (score 6):

Here's another solution:

```
dd = dir('*.csv');

fileNames = {dd.name}; 

data = cell(numel(fileNames),2);
data(:,1) = regexprep(fileNames, '.csv','');

for ii = 1:numel(fileNames)    
   data{ii,2} = dlmread(fileNames{ii});
end
```

This will output something like

```
data = 
    'test1.csv'    [2x15000 double]
    'test2.csv'    [2x15000 double]
    etc.
```

With this approach, there's really no need to have a zillion variable names flying about. Using cell-arrays in situations like these is generally considered the better way to go; the zillion-variable names approach is "not done".

Comment: +1 I like your solution better. I'll be removing mine now... :)

Answer (score 4):

I would rather use structures, not variables, to read the individual files:

```
files=dir('*.csv');
for file = files
    varname = regexp(file.name, '^.\w+', 'match');
    varname = genvarname(varname{:});
    data.(varname) = csvread(file.name);
end
```

If you want dynamic variables, you will end up using `eval`, which is not recommended and dangerous.

Comment: +1, but what if a filename contains a space? :p

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis already fixed ;)

Comment: wasn't `csvread` going to be removed in favor of `dlmread`? I vaguely remember a warning like that in the help...I have R2010 here, so I can't test it for R2012

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis don't see anything in the matlab documentation about it. Maybe they changed their minds?

Comment: oh well. Remembered incorrectly then :p