# Iterate through Files, loading images - Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, iteration

I have some 1000 images I need to load as training data for a facial recognition program.

There are 100 people, each have 10 unique pictures.

Saved in a folder like:

```
    myTraining  //main folder
         - John // sub folder
               - John_Smith_001, John_Smith_002, ... , 00n, //images
         - Mary // sub folder
               - Mary_Someone_001... you get the idea :)
```

I'm familiar with a lot of matlab but not ways of iterating through external files.

What is an easy implementation to go through each folder, one by one and load the images, ideally using the retrieving the file names and using them as variable/image names.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Matlab 2013, Windows, sorry about that.

Comment: See this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621846/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-in-matlab

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab) question. Exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
basePath = pwd;  %your base path which is in your case myTraining  
allPaths = dir(basePath);  %get all directory content
subFolders = [allPaths(:).isdir]; %get only indices of folders
foldersNames = {allPaths(subFolders).name}'; % filter folders names
foldersNames(ismember(foldersNames,{'.','..'})) = []; %delete default paths for parents return '.','..'
for i=1:length(foldersNames), %loop through all folders
    tmp = foldersNames{i};  %get folder by index
    p = strcat([basePath '\']); 
    currentPath =strcat([p tmp]); % add base to current folder
    cd(currentPath);   % change directory to new path
    files = dir('*.jpg'); % list all images in your path which in your case could be John or Mary 
    for j=1:length(files), % loop through your images 
        img = imread(files(j).name); % read each image and do what you want 
    end
end
```

Comment: Ah this is the type of thing I was looking for I think. Thanks for taking the time to post.

Comment: seems a bit lengthy to do what is needed, don't you think? If the OS already has this functionality built in, why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2):

Using the following commands will recursively list all files in a specific directory and its sub-directories. I have listed it for both Windows and Mac/Linux. I unfortunately can not test the Mac/Linux version since I am not near any of those machines, but it will be fairly similar to what is written below.

**Windows**

```
[~,result] = system('dir C:\Users\username\Desktop /a-d /s /b');
files = regexp(result,'\n','Split')
```

**Mac/Linux**

```
[~,result] = system('find /some/Directory -type file);
files = regexp(result,'\n','Split')
```

You can then iterate through the cell array created, `files`, and do whatever loading you may need with `imread`, or something like that

Answer (score 1):

for jpg images it would be

```
files = dir('*.jpg');
for file = files'
    img = imread(file.name);
    % Do some stuff
end
```

and if you have multiple extensions use

```
files = [dir('*.jpg'); dir('*.gif')]
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for posting. That's nice to know.