# How to concatenate strings in a loop?

Tags: string, matlab

How to concatenate strings in a loop?
For example I have this character array

```
fruits = char('apple','pear')
```

I would like to see this output

```
  apple tart
  pear tart
```

But when I use this loop:

```
for f = fruits'
  strcat(f," tart")
end
```

The output is

```
ans =

a tart
p tart
p tart
l tart
e tart

ans =

p tart
e tart
a tart
r tart
 tart
```

In fact I need this to read a bunch of csv files in a directory. Part of the file name is a variable over which I want to loop over. For example my directory contains the 2 following files from which I want to read data:

```
peartart.csv
appletart.csv
```

This [other answer using a list of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621846/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-in-matlab) is nice but then I have no control over the `fruit` variable name in the file. I wand control over this variable because I will perform a statistical test for each fruit data and store the test result with the fruit name in another file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `fruits = char('apple','pear')` you create a natrix of chars. Closest to a list of strings is a cell array.

```
fruits = {'apple','pear'}
```

Opening a csv should be something like:

```
for f = fruits
  csvread([f{:},'tart.csv'])
end
```

Not sure if the blank before the t is required or not, depends on your file name.

Comment: Thank you, the loop works. Now I have a trouble opening a csv file at each iteration for f = fruits' 
data = csvread(char(strcat(char(f),'tart','.csv'))); 
disp(char(f)); 
disp(data); 
end;

Comment: Neat, I didn't know that was possible!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without loops using `cellfun` if `fruits` is a cell array:

```
fruits = {'apple','pear'};
tarts = cellfun(@(x)strcat(x,' tart'),fruits,'UniformOutput',false)
```

You can then access the strings with `tarts{i}`:

```
>> tarts{1}

ans =

apple tart
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to load a csv file at each loop iteration. Something like data = csvread(char(strcat('apple','tart','.csv')))

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution, use a cell array of strings:

```
fruits={'apple','pear'};
for i_fruit = 1:length(fruits)
  strcat(fruits{i_fruit},' tart')
end
```

Comment: Thank you, however you are using an index `i_fruit` and I would prefer to loop directly over fruit names, as I wrote in a comment on @daniel 's answer. His answer works but I don't manage to use it to open files in a loop so I resort to your solution with indexes.  for i_fruit = 1:length(fruits)
 data = csvread(strcat(fruits{i_fruit},'tart','.csv')); disp(data); end

Comment: Daniel updated his answer and I can now loop directly over the variable name and can use it to open file names in a loop. See accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

fruits is a 2D array of size 2x5. When you do

```
for f=fruits'
```

you are converting fruits to a 1D column array and looping over each element. You should loop over each row instead, like this:

```
fruits = char('apple','pear');
for ii=1:size(fruits,1)
   strcat(fruits(i,:),' tart')
end
```

This outputs:

```
ans =

apple tart


ans =

pear tart
```