# How can I read all files in a folder with dlmread?

Tags: matlab

I have to read a lot of text files in a folder which only have one matrix in them. So I found and tested that `dlmread` is good when I write a file's name. But I couldn't have MATLAB read them all.

How can I correct this small code and If there is better way, please write.

```
files = dir('C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\a\*.txt')
for k = 1:length(files)
    fname= files(k).name
    M = dlmread('fname')   % This part is wrong
    % REST OF CODE for each Matrix M
end
```

well `fname` really reads the name of file, `1.txt` for example. If I write `M = dlmread('1.txt')` myself, it reads matrix to `M`, but if I write `M = dlmread('fname')` it does not.

How can I do this best?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621846/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-in-matlab -- I didn't really get what you want.

Comment: well fname really reads the name of file, 1.txt for example. If I write M = dlmread('1.txt') , it reads matrix to M, but if I write M = dlmread('fname') it does not. What should i do and How can i correct it. Thanks

Comment: @xcbnm: ah got you. Should have seen it directly in the code. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need:

```
for k=1:numel(files)
    fname = fullfile('C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\a', files(k).name);
    M = dlmread(fname);
    % ...
end
```

Two things:

1. `fname` is a variable, not a literal string
2. since the files are not in the current directory, you have to specify the full path

Comment: Thank you very much, I will accept it but i have to wait 10 minutes. Thanks again