# Import Data from multiple text files

Tags: matlab, text

I'm currently working on a study where the data is saved in .txt files for each participants. I'm looking for a way to load all the data from each files into matlab automatically. 
I've found many topic on loading multpile files, but i can't find a way to make it work for me.

I want to load all the files called "Log_*" into a table that goes like that:

```
delim = {')(',') ','(', ' ', ','};
T = readtable('Log_***.txt','Delimiter', delim,'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);
T = removevars (T, {'Var1', 'Var2', 'Var4', 'Var6', 'Var8', 'Var10', 'Var12','Var14', 'Var16', 'Var18', 'Var26', 'Var27', 'Var31', 'Var36', 'Var40', 'Var45', 'Var47', 'Var49'});
newnames = {'essai', 'DureeEssai', 'azVoulue', 'elVoulu', 'azMesure','elMesure', 'distanceAngulaire', 'diffhorizontale', 'diffElevation', 'x1', 'y1', 'z1', 'x2', 'y2', 'z2', 'posTx', 'posTy', 'postz', 'oriTx', 'oriTy', 'oriTz', 'oriTw', 'posCx', 'posCy', 'posCz', 'oriCx', 'oriCy', 'oriCz','oriCw','distanceAngulaire_oriT_C','az_oriT','el_oriT'};    
T.Properties.VariableNames = newnames;
T = T(2:2:end,:);
```

This works for one file at a time, but i can't manage to write a proper script to get it done for every file at once. 
If you know the way, i'd be glad if you could share it.

Cheers

Comment: You will have to use [dir](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) and loop over the files

Comment: There is an example in [Loop through files in a folder in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11621846/5358968)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! 
I now have this:
`files = dir('Log_*.txt');
for file = files'
    txt = importdata(file.name);
    delim = {')(',') ','(', ' ', ','};
    txt = cellfun(@(x)strsplit(x,delim),txt,'UniformOutput',false);
    txt = cat(1,txt{:});
end`
But it only loads the number of row that every files have (67).
I've also tried the script with k= 1:length(xx) but i get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Using [dir](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) and [matrix concatenation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html), you can append one row of a table to the end of another table:

```
T = table;
list_of_files = dir(**directory of files**);
for i = 1:length(list_of_files)
    filename_to_use = list_of_files(i).name;
    U = table;

    **read file in and place data into table**

    T = [T; U];
    clear U;
end
disp(T);
```

This is if you want all your data to be stored in one table.